# not able to plot different labels for different live graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

actually trying to make 4 different live graphs using mat plot lib but its but they don't have their own x and y labels  want all of them to be completely  different using subplot but don't know what going wrong.  make 4  subplots and plot them accprding to right syntax

I try them to by defining ax[j, k]. xaxis the graph are working well but they don't have their own x and y label i try different method but all get me a problem
fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='all', sharey='all')

```
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame1)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    global x,y1


    self.x = np.linspace(0, 4, 241)
    x = []
    y1 = []
    t = []

    def animate(i, x, y1):

        
            temp_c = self.var

            
            x.append(i)
            y1.append(temp_c)

            for j in range(2):
                for k in range(2):
                    self.ax[j, k].clear()

                    
                    self.ax[j, k].plot(x, y1, linewidth=2)


    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(x, y1), interval=1000)
    # plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Not sure if I understood you problem correctly (apologies if not). Why are you using ```sharex='all', sharey='all'``` if you want them not to share?

Comment: can u plz tell me where?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ax[j, k].set_xlabel("your-x-label")` and `ax[j, k].set_ylabel("your-y-label")` for every subplot and set different labels for them.

Comment: Actually label is not a problem i want  x and y values for each graph

Comment: I´m sorry, but in this case I don´t understand your problem. Do you want every datapoint to be labeled? Is your problem, that all plots look the same? Maybe I can help you if you clarified your question.